# How to get td values based on span.text?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to gather some balance sheet metrics/values from Reuters.

For example, I want to get the last three years' value of "*Total Assets*". I am able to find the according `span.text` but how do I get the values for the last three years 2020, 2019 and 2018 of it? I know that they are stored in a `td` value but I have no clue to hop into that `td`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_balance  = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/AAPL.OQ/financials/balance-sheet-annual'
page = requests.get(url_balance)

if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    spans = soup.findAll('span')
    for span in spans:
        if span.text == 'Total Assets':
            #total_asset_val_2020 = ???     How to get the value of Total Asset 2020 into that variable?
            #total_asset_val_2019 = ???     How to get the value of Total Asset 2019 into that variable?
            #total_asset_val_2018 = ???     How to get the value of Total Asset 2018 into that variable?
            print(span.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try out,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_balance = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/AAPL.OQ/financials/balance-sheet-annual'
page = requests.get(url_balance)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

dates_ = ["20", "19", "18", "17", "16"]
total_assets = (
    i.text for i in soup.find("span", text="Total Assets").parent.parent.find_all("td")
    if i.text.strip()
)

print(list(zip(dates_, total_assets)))
```

---

```
[('20', '323,888.00'), ('19', '338,516.00'), ('18', '365,725.00'), ('17', '375,319.00'), ('16', '321,686.00')]
```